# Ordem de execução numa Promise

Tags: javascript, promises

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
const execute = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.info('Iniciou');
             resolve('Executando');
             console.info('Finalizou');
        }, 1000);
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.info(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};

execute();
```

Como podem notar a execução desse código gera como saida:

```
// Iniciou
// Finalizou
// Executando
```

Sinceramente não tenho idéia do porque disso ocorrer, se alguém puder me esclarecer essa dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em uma promise quando você retorna o resultado 'resolve' o que você está fazendo e envia o resultado para o 'then' sendo assíncrona esta ação e executando a funcionalidade posteriormente de resolve imediatamente.

A coisa certa fazer o resolve o último:

```js
const execute = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.info('Iniciou');
             console.info('Executando');
             resolve('Finalizou');
        }, 1000);
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.info(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
};

execute();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.